# MYSQL COUNTING RIGHT ANSWERS WITH 3 TABLES (USER - ANSWERS - QUESTIONS)

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have 3 tables:

USER:

- USERID
- NAME
- COMPANY
- AGE

QUESTIONS:

- SETID (IDENTIFY ALL QUESTION FROM THE SAME GROUP)
- QUESTIONID
- QUESTION (like "Who is the USA's President?")
- ANSWER "A"
- ANSWER "B"
- ANSWER "C"
- ANSWER "D"
- CORRECT ANSWER (as CA)

ANSWERS:

- USERID
- ANSWERFORQUESTION1 (as AFQ1)
- ANSWERFORQUESTION2 (as AFQ2)
- ANSWERFORQUESTION3... (Will be 20 Questions)
- LAST ANSWER (as LA) <<< I use this to know what is the last answer of each user and post the next answer to him.. (IF 21 = "ALL DONE!")

### I have 2 issues:

1-I Need to count the % of "Correct Answers" for each Answer.

2-I Need to count the % of "Correct Answers" for each Answer - for COMPANY "A", COMPANY "B"... (will be 5 companies)

TO SOLVE ISSUE 1:

```
select 
    count(DISTINCT ANSWERS.USERID) as TOTAL,

    sum(case when ANSWERS.AFQ1 = QUESTIONS.CA AND ANSWERS.LA = 21 AND QUESTIONS.QUESTIONID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AT1,
    sum(case when ANSWERS.AFQ2 = QUESTIONS.CA AND ANSWERS.LA = 21 AND QUESTIONS.QUESTIONID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AT2,

   (....until 20)

from ANSWERS, QUESTIONS
Where ANSWERS.LA = 21
```

With this I got a Table with TOTAL ANSWERS (COMPLETED = 21) - AND AT1, AT2, AT3.. with each total "correct answers" for each answer.

Then I can do a AT1/TOTAL to get all %.

Issue 1 is ok.

But how I can do the same for Issue 2?

tks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 select 
        COMPANY,count(DISTINCT ANSWERS.USERID) as TOTAL,

        sum(case when ANSWERS.AFQ1 = QUESTIONS.CA AND ANSWERS.LA = 21 AND QUESTIONS.QUESTIONID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AT1,
        sum(case when ANSWERS.AFQ2 = QUESTIONS.CA AND ANSWERS.LA = 21 AND QUESTIONS.QUESTIONID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) AT2,

       (....until 20)

  from ANSWERS a, QUESTIONS
  join user u on u.userid = a.userid 
  Where ANSWERS.LA = 21
  group by u.COMPANY
```

**Hint 1:** `join` with USER table on Answer.Userid = User.userid

**Hint 2:** use `GROUP BY` for COMPANY

Note : My syntax may be wrong. I have used SQL server syntax.

Comment: Hi @Backtrack! Tks for your time and help! The syntax was a little wrong - SQL cannot find "ANSWERS.USERID" - I change the syntax to: FROM QUESTIONS JOIN ANSWERS ON QUESTIONS.SET = 1 JOIN USERS ON USERS.USERID = ANSWERS.USERID WHERE ANSWERS.LA = 21 GROUP BY USERS.COMPANY - Its give me all 5 companies with total and all 20 questions with "correct answers" - BUT - THE SUM/COUNT is counting duplicated "USERIDs" - UserID isnt the primary key - How can I make a DISTINCT here? tks a lot!

Comment: I Try Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN.... ) but this bring me a wrong count... Total is 15. With Sum(case when..) I got 16 (duplicate - 16 answers >15 total) - For COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN) I got only 2! - The right count is 9. 9 users answers this question correctly. (and 6 wrong).. tks!